# Problem with implementing a SSL Service Client with GroovyWS[Groovy/Grails]

Tags: grails, groovy, groovyws

I am new bie to GroovyWS.

I like to consume SSL webservice in my Grails Application. So far i have following piece of code collected from

```
  def myServiceUrl ="https://myserverurl/services/myservicename"
  Map<String, String> mapClient = [
                                     "https.keystore":"",
                                     "https.keystore.pass":"",
                                     "https.truststore":"",
                                     "https.truststore.pass":"client"
                                    ]

    def proxy = new WSClient(myServiceUrl +"?wsdl", this.class.classLoader)
    proxy.setSSLProperties(mapClient)
    proxy.setBasicAuthentication("username","password")
    proxy.initialize()
```

but it all end up with an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at groovyx.net.ws.cxf.SSLHelper.getLocalWsdlUrl(SSLHelper.java:253)
```

I want to know how can i get worked aforewritten piece of code ?
So far i have used GroovyWS
Is there any other way to implement WS client in Grails/Groovy ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Groovy JIRA report [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-122) is suggesting that the password to your keystore may be different.

Comment: i think here my problem is getting or configuring keystore as well as truststore. can you please suggest mey any link where i can collect desired information